# Windows Server 2019 как сделать RDP более 3х пользователей?

Tags: сервер, windows-server, rdp

Столкнулся с проблемой ограничения пользователей RDP.
Как можно исправить народными средствами?

Comment: Поднять на нём службу удалённых рабочих столов и установить необходимое количество клиентских лицензий.